# CryptGetUserKey function fails with no errors

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, cryptoapi

I've been playing around with `CryptoAPI` and everything was fine.

I've imported `.PFX` to the certificate store, got context, got `CSP` handle. Every function I've been using I've checked for the mistakes with `GetLastError` function. But when I'd called `CryptGetUserKey` with three arguments which are `hCryptProv`, `dwKeySpec` and pointer to `UserKey`, I got an error, but `GetLastError` call didn't show me anything but a random value like `2148073485` that means nothing I suppose.

How can I find out what is wrong?

OS - Windows 7 32b HP;

Programming language - C++;

IDE - MSVS2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Look into using the `FormatMessage` function to convert `GetLastError` error codes to error messages. This will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> GetLastError call didn't show me anything but a random value like 2148073485 that means nothing I suppose.

You fail WINAPI forever. It took me like five seconds to launch Calc.exe and convert it to hex: `8009000D`, which looks like a perfectly valid error HRESULT.

---

Let's take some time to analyze it a bit more:

- 8 is ERROR.
- 9 is not 7, meaning it's not a regular Win32 error. A search in Visual C++ headers tells me 9 is FACILITY_SSPI.
- If I search 8009000D in Visual C++ headers, I get this line:
  `#define NTE_NO_KEY _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(0x8009000DL)` There, you have it, it's your error: NTE_NO_KEY.
- MSDN is [rather unhelpful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915314.aspx), but Google shows some other questions about the NTE_NO_KEY error, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272822/error-with-cryptdecrypt-winapi-function).